# Php require_once new file no such file or directory

Tags: php, nginx

I created a file in php that I want to include in my project.

I put `require_once __DIR__.'/file_1.php';`
And I get the error:

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/my/main/file_1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/my/main/index.php`

Before I wanted to add my new file there was aleady a `require_once` for another file in the same location that works.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/file_that_was.php'; -> works
require_once __DIR__.'/file_1.php'; -> doesn't work
```

My new file has the same permissions as the one that works.

`file_1.php` doesn't have any errors. It's just a simple echo.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you put the new file (file_1.php) in the same directory of the old file (file_that_was.php)?

Comment: both `file_that_was.php` and `file_1.php` in the same directory?And what are the permissions of both files?

Comment: Yes. It's in the same directory.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing the file structure. Are you sure there are no errors in file_1.php? Maybe try renaming it to see if it's the underscore? (I don't think it is, just spitballing)

Comment: Sounds weird but this might be a caching issue

Comment: add output of `ls -alh var/www/my/**/**`

Comment: Interesting. The file doesn't show when I run your command.

Comment: It also doesn't show when I `ls -l` the folder. But why?

Comment: what the permission of that file?